# Can I request a revision to a recommendation letter after I’ve accepted it?

Tags: linkedin

I’ve accepted a recommendation letter on LinkedIn. Can I still request that my recommender revise the letter?

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that the answer is yes. In your profile, scroll to the recommendations and click the edit button (the pencil icon). In the menu that appears, you’ll see “Request Revision” below each accepted recommendation.